# network cutting software

Tags: communication, windows-phone

There's a whole bunch of cellphones in my room (15 in total) and during some days in the night I'd like to cut the network connection to all of them at once so they don't disturb me, doing this one by one would definitely (and has been taking) a lot of time, So I'd like to know if there is a PC software, that cuts off the network (NOTE: NOT THE WLAN NETWORK, the whole cellphone network) of these cellphones? I'd prefer open source softwares if possible, though please recommend any softwares.

Comment: you expect a PC to stop radio waves? seriously?

Comment: From the tag I assume you're talking about Windows phones? Don't they have some setting/profile for "silent times" you could trigger from..until a given time? If not, aren't there apps to do that? As @MarkYisri pointed out, apar from a remote-controlled slege-hammer I cannot think of a way a PC could achieve that (and the action of that sledge-hammer has the nasty side-effect of not being revertible).

Comment: Note that disrupting cellphone communication is illegal in many countries

Comment: @Mark Yisri, Well, I'm not a techie, but ijust stopping them from ringing with a single button

Comment: @bzal how do you do that?

Comment: @MarkYisri, I don't know, that's why I'm asking here

Answer (score 1):

There is a app called "tasker" which can switch your phones into airplane mode.
You only have to decide how to trigger it. You make it time triggered.
Or triggered by a android intent. Or when a special email arrives in the K9 mail client. Or you could use notifymyandroid.com to trigger it in tasker.
Or you could do it by a SMS. Many possibilities.

Comment: exactly, that's the one, "tasker", if I can switch my phones to airplane, with a single button, that would be cool

Comment: Note: [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) only runs on Android devices. And it's about USD/EUR 5 (free 7 day trial available). Definitely worth it, I'm using it for years. For details on its possibilities, see [my resource collection on Tasker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker).

Comment: @jms, then it's not gonna stop all of the phones, some of them are entry level cells, some iphones, and some are on tizen os.

Comment: @bzal of course! PCs can't stop radio waves!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [setting up Quiet Hours](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-configure-quiet-hours-windows-10) on all of your phones which will block calls within a certain timeframe.

Comment: I think it's only for windows phones, ??